Generalizing a Result From Polyas Problem Book in Analysis about differentiation of power series
Within the classic book Problems in Analysis by George Polya and Gabor Szego in the section on operations and differentiation of power series, problem 48 states the following:
"Suppose that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two polynomials relatively primes, that the degree of $g(x)$ is not smaller than the degree of $f(x)$ and that $g(0)=0$, $g(k) \neq 0$ for $k=1, 2, \cdots$ The series $y=1+\frac{f(1)}{g(1)} z+ \frac{f(1) f(2)}{g(1) g(2)} z^2 + \frac{f(1) f(2) f(3)}{g(1) g(2) g(3)} z^3 + \cdots$ satisfies the linear homogeneous differential equation $g\left(z \frac{d}{dz}\right)y = f\left(z \frac{d}{dz}\right) z y.$ "
where in this context $z\frac{d}{dz}$ is a differential operator which differentiates with respect to z then multiplies by z.
This result seems fairly general but I am wondering how it can be modified for functions which might skip over certain powers of z in the expansion. Take n to be a natural number then what would the corresponding differential equation be for a function y of the form $y=1+\frac{f(1)}{g(1)} z^n+ \frac{f(1) f(2)}{g(1) g(2)} z^{2n} + \frac{f(1) f(2) f(3)}{g(1) g(2) g(3)} z^{3n} + \cdots$
perhaps even more generally I might wonder what the corresponding result would be for an arithmetic progression in the powers of z. That is, what differential equation would correspond to the function $y=z^{b}+\frac{f(1)}{g(1)} z^{n+b}+ \frac{f(1) f(2)}{g(1) g(2)} z^{2n+b} + \frac{f(1) f(2) f(3)}{g(1) g(2) g(3)} z^{3n+b} + \cdots$
fundamentally my question seems related to asking that if a function $y(z)$ satisfies an ordinary differential equation. what is the corresponding differential equation for $y(z^n)$?
Any help on generalizing and understanding this result more deeply or in a broader context would be greatly appreciated.
